# How to copy by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have  a DataTables plugin defined as

```
var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
      'aaData': data,
      'aoColumns': columns,
      'bScrollInfinite': true,
      'bScrollCollapse': true,
      'iDisplayLength': 20,
      'sScrollY': '300px'
});

var oTable_Copy = oTable.slice();
```

Now whenever any value in `oTable` changes, the corresponding value also changes in `oTable_Copy`. How do I prevent `oTable_Copy` from changing?

Comment: You would have to do a clone... all you're doing is copying references.

Comment: Create a clone of `$('#table1')` first and call `dataTable` again. Or maybe you can clone `oTable`, but I don't know how `dataTable` works internally, so creating a clone of the DOM element and just applying the plugin again might be the safer way.

Comment: Why not just create another element and do `$('#table1, #table2').dataTable(obj)` or something similar, what do you expect to achieve by this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to clone an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that you accepted the given answer. `oTable` is a jQuery object containing DOM elements. Converting to and from JSON doesn't work in this case. Why did you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way (assuming no loops) would be

```
var yourDeepCopyObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oTable));
```

Comment: This doesn't work with DOM elements, which is what the OP is using here. I'm really surprised this answer was accepted.

Comment: as i said - assuming no loops. you can try .extend(true, source, dest) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: But there are loops in this case. And possible event handlers and other state. Converting to and from JSON is not a solution for this problem. There is no point in making assumptions that can't be fulfilled anyway. *edit:* `$.extend` is not useful for cloning DOM elements either.